# how to find duplicate entrys in below structured table in mysql

Tags: mysql

How do I find duplicate entries in the following MySQL table? My concern is that the table is 500 MB in size and growing.

```
CREATE TABLE `phone_observations` (
`email_address` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
`phone_number` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
`phone_type` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unknown',
`unix_time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`guid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`spammy` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
KEY `phone_observations_phone_number` (`phone_number`),
KEY `phone_numbers_phone_type` (`phone_type`),
KEY `idx_spam` (`spammy`),
KEY `idx_guid_mail_time` (`guid`,`email_address`,`unix_time`)
`unique_phone_observations` (`email_address`,`phone_number`,`unix_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I am not sure where to begin.

Comment: How is it related to javascript?

Comment: I changed the tag to `mysql` instead of `javascript`, did not make sense. Anyways, what have you tried? In its current state this question shows no research effort at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `c`, `email_address`, `phone_number`, ... /* list all your columns here */
FROM `phone_observations`
GROUP BY `email_address`, `phone_number`, ... /* list all your columns here */
HAVING `c`>1
```